# Apply form extension to some Symfony forms but not others

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am designing a Symfony bundle that has two distinct types of forms:

- Some "regular" forms
- Some forms that are used exclusively in a REST API

For the latter group, I need to inject some services and apply some customization. I'd prefer to do this without declaring each form as its own service.

My thought was to do this:

- Register a new form type that extends "form" with its own name like "api"
- Extend that new "api" type for each form I wish to create
- Create a form extension that is tagged to this "api" type
- Within the extension, inject the services, apply transformation, etc.

The goal here is to make it extremely simple to bake in this extended functionality to new forms, for example by extending a new type or implementing a marker interface.

I was able to make most of the above work with one exception: I could only do it if I tagged the extension to "form", which then applied it to all forms. I haven't been able to get an extension to only target a subset of forms.

Is there any way to do this, or will I have to live with a less elegant solution?

Comment: Don't you have to declare every form as a new service any way?

Comment: I typically create some form like `MyType extends AbstractType` and then in a controller do something like `$myForm = $this->createForm(new MyType(), $object);`. If you are not injecting anything into the form, there is no need to register it as its own service in the container (although nothing is stopping you from doing so). My personal preference is to reduce the amount of configuration/service definition as much as possible, but I know some others have the opposite view.

Comment: Fair enough. I usually go for the opposite approach of making everything a service and then either calling/injecting it as a service or using it as a field via the alias. If you were to set it as a service then (I think) you would be able to use an abstract service as a base with a set of arguments and then just use that as a parent for each new service but with different tags. Not your ideal approach but minimal config.